Where Does Chromium Get OS Information Displayed in navigator.platform?
I'm trying to understand how Chromium determines the operating system type. I found information suggesting that Chromium uses the uname utility, which retrieves data from the kernel using the utsname function.
           struct utsname {
               char sysname[];    /* Operating system name (e.g., "Linux") */
               char nodename[];   /* Name within "some implementation-defined
                                     network" */
               char release[];    /* Operating system release (e.g., "2.6.28") */
               char version[];    /* Operating system version */
               char machine[];    /* Hardware identifier */
           #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
               char domainname[]; /* NIS or YP domain name */
           #endif
           };


I changed the sysname value (from Linux to Windows), which supposedly determines the OS type, but Chromium still shows Linux, while in Firefox, navigator.platform displays Windows.
Has anyone encountered this before? What could be the reason for this behavior?

Generally, the target OS for a binary executable is defined at compile time. You could run e.g. file on the binary. This is also reflected in quite a few preprocessor macros in C and C++, which may be from where it gets picked up. Extract a [mcve] and/or run the code in a debugger to find out.
